# C - Function with alias?

Tags: c

Debian 64 bits testing.
Gcc 4.8.x and gcc 4.9.x

I came across the function in glibc :

```
int
rename (old, new)
     const char *old;
     const char *new;
{
  if (old == NULL || new == NULL)
    {
      __set_errno (EINVAL);
      return -1;
    }

  __set_errno (ENOSYS);
  return -1;
}


stub_warning (rename)
```

My problem is

```
int
rename (old, new)
     const char *old;
     const char *new;
{
...
}
```

When I try to compile it throws :

`declaration for parameter ‘old’ but no such parameter`

Same for new.

**What happens ?**

**What is that syntax ?**

Thank you

## Update:

I really mean it :
[Look at that code, which is the same as glibc](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cvs/cvs-19/cvs/lib/rename.c)

## Update2:

It works now. A typo messed the whole thing. It should work flawlessly for you.

Comment: For this problem it would be usefull to get to know what compiler you are compiling with, in what enviroment do you compile and what compiling flags do you set.

Comment: gcc compiles by default with `-std=gnu99` (AFAIK) this mode doesn't support the c identifier list. try it with explicit `-std=c90` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the old style of function definitions (technically C called it a function definition with a *identifier-list form for the parameter declaration*). It's an obsolescent feature in C and the behavior has some slight differences with prototypes declarations and definitions.

Use the prototype form instead:

```
int
rename (const char *old, const char *new)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Ok but it still compiles for glibc but not for my test example. Why ?

Comment: @Kroma try to compile with -std=c90

Comment: Same. There is something going on

Comment: @Kroma: The error is caused by something else. Does your compiler produce other diagnostics? Can you post your complete code or a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @Kroma the old-style is obsolescent but is still valid in c99. How do you compile this, did you include this function definition in your program? If yes it may collide with the declaration of the real `rename` function; rename your function `rename` to something like `my_rename`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you meant to do

```
int rename(const char *old, const char *new)
{
...
}
```

Comment: I updated the question to show an original source showing the implementation I am talking about